# How to update a single row at a time of SQL Server 2008 using ASP.NET?

Tags: html, asp.net, sql-server

I have a form in which i have the following fields as shown in image :

[Image of the form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xRVqz.jpg)

Below is the screenshot of database in which I have three inserted 3 different  values for 3 different row, but when I updated one of the rows among them, all three rows got updated.

[Image of the rows in database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hZ5Oq.jpg)

Here is update code I have on `SqlDataSource`:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
     ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ToursandTravelsConnectionString %>" 
     SelectCommand="SELECT [subcatname], [subcatid], [categoryname] FROM [subcategory]" 
     UpdateCommand="UPDATE subcategory SET subcatname =@1, categoryname =@2, pic =@3">
     <UpdateParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="txtsubcategoryname" Name="1" 
            PropertyName="Text" />
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="txtcategoryname" Name="2" 
            PropertyName="Text" />
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="FileUpload1" Name="3" 
            PropertyName="FileBytes" />
    </UpdateParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: here is the image of controls instead of which i have used @1,@2,@3 [https://i.stack.imgur.com/zLOEI.jpg]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a `where` clause for your `update`. Something like this:

```
UpdateCommand="UPDATE subcategory SET subcatname =@1, categoryname =@2, pic =@3 WHERE subcatid = @4">
    <UpdateParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="txtsubcategoryname" Name="1" 
            PropertyName="Text" />
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="txtcategoryname" Name="2" 
            PropertyName="Text" />
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="FileUpload1" Name="3" 
            PropertyName="FileBytes" />
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="intsubcategoryid" Name="4" 
            PropertyName="Integer" />
    </UpdateParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: @MohammedHussainMerchant whichever control corresponds to the `subcatid` in the database.

Comment: Thank you so much bro got a perfect answer from your side... :)

Comment: @MohammedHussainMerchant It looks like you are still learning, so please do not take offense, but: You should not have `categoryname` on the `subcategory` table because you can end up with bad data. e.g. When you updated the `categoryname` on the `subcategory` table but not in the `category` table -- or the other way around.

Comment: thanks bro for your advice ,I m still a noob working on a college last year project so dont have much idea thanks for it i ll make the changes .. :)

Comment: @MohammedHussainMerchant No problem, it's good to learn these things early. Feel free to post more questions.